# BottomNavigationBar in flutter is transparent now?

Tags: flutter

Im learning Flutter and I added a BottomnavigationBar and it was blue for a day and then I came back to it being clear and im not sure what happened because I did not change my code at all.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book),
            label: 'Mags',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.star_outlined),
            label: 'Featured',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
            label: 'Saved',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.apps_rounded),
            label: 'Shelf',
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

I tried changing the backgroundcolor but it did not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `backgroundColor` of the `BottomNavigationBar` changes depending on the item you have selected which defaults to white. You have to define the color on every `BottomNavigationBarItem`.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Icon(Icons.book),
  label: 'Mags',
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
),
```

And when that item is active the NavigationBar will turn in that color.